# assign an object value conditionally?

Tags: javascript, react-native, jsx

is there a way in Javascript (jsx for react native) to assign an object value conditional? something like this

```
startDate = 5
var daysgo = 30



//it has to be an obj
startDate={(startDate != null) ? startDate : daysgo} 

console.log(startDate) // it should either print 5 or 30 if startDate is null
```

Comment: yes, there is. but your code is all over the place. to simplify things, take a look at this code: const a = 'a'; const b = 'b'; const x = {y: a === 'a' ? a : b}; console.log(x.y); If you change a to other than a, it will print 'b'. If you want an object, then do console.log(x), it will print {y: 'a'} or {y:'b'} depending on a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this way

```js
let startDate = 5
let daysgo = 30

//it has to be an obj
startDate=(startDate != null) ? {startDate: startDate} : {startDate: daysgo}

console.log(startDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have many ways to conditionally assign values to object in js

But i think it's the good way for you:

```
const targetValue = {key: candidateValue || defaultValue }
```

This LOC mean. if key get `candidateValue` first,. Ff it is `falsy`, then get `defaultValue`.

> Note: More about [Falsy values in JS](https://guide.freecodecamp.org/javascript/falsy-values/)